# router is assigning a different private ip address for my intranet

Tags: router, dhcp-server

I have a rog ag11000 router setup as the main router, and also have a DDWrt linksys router connected to it via lan cable and configured to work as an extender (DHCP server off).

The gateway ip address (main router) is 192.168.50.1 however, sometimes when I try to connect to connect to it with different devices, the DHCP server will give an ip address like if it was in a different private network. It will assign 192.168.15.x. Obviously devices assigned to these ips will not have any kind of internet connectivity.

Any clues what it could be the ip assignation problem??

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can try logging into your router GUI and going to LAN option on the left hand side and then select DHCP Server. From here is where you can configure the pool which should allow you to set a Starting and Ending address. These are the only addresses that should be issued out by the Router.

Hope this helps! If not, let me know and we can try more :)

Comment: The problem is that the devices are getting ip addresses from a different gateway. 192.168.15.x instead of 192.168.50.x, and I dont know exactly why, since there is only 1 DHCP server enabled in the main router.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the following setup:

- Cable from ag11000 router in LAN port connected to Linksys router in LAN port (not the WAN port).
- ag11000 router LAN IP address set to 192.168.50.1
- Linksys router LAN IP address set to 192.168.50.2 (last octect can be any from 2-254)
- Ensure DHCP is turned off on Linksys router
- Assuming ag1000 router handles DHCP, it must exclude the IP address of the Linksys Router.
- And for good measure, the Linksys router must be told the gateway IP address (the ag11000 router's IP address) and the DNS address (the ag11000 router's IP address).

This setup should get you going.

P.S. If you want to use the WAN port on your Linksys, as per this document [Adding WAN Port to LAN Switch to use as an additional, normal LAN port](https://forum.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/WAN_Port), you just need to check the box 'Assign WAN Port to Switch'.

[image: Connect two routers]

Comment: Everything was all set exactly like you mentiioned, using the WAN port assigned to LAN. The only thing i added was the ag11000 ip as the DNS in the ddwrt router. Hope this solves the problem.

Comment: Try putting the cable into the LAN port for the Linksys router, just to rule it out.